# How to structure Yocto conf files for two different machines and same bblayers

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm currently trying to setup my distro Yocto layer to generate a build environment for two different machines: `robocop` and `terminator`. The `conf/machine/` containing these machine.conf files are present in a different layer.
Also, I would like to use the same `bblayers.conf` for setups.

The first idea was to make two separate conf directories:

```
conf/variant/robocop

conf/variant/terminator
```

Each containing a `local.conf.sample` (with the respective `MACHINE` value) and `bblayers.conf.sample` file.

The problem with this is that I am basically duplicating bblayers in both directories. Since the `TEMPLATECONF` var must point to a place where both files are present. Therefore I cannot separate `local.conf.sample` and `bblayers.conf.sample`

The other alternative is to leave both files under `conf/` directory as generic and selecting the machine when bitbaking: `MACHINE=robocop bitbake core-image-minimal`. But I would like to avoid this as it is easy for the developer to forget to prepend the machine variable before building something.

Is there another alternative to allow two different `local.conf` using the same `bblayers.conf` ?

Also I would like to use is thread and ask for which usecases should one use `*.conf` or `*.conf.sample` files.

Comment: I currently have the same bblayers input for many different machines. They images are built under different areas of course. The simplest route is probably to enforce the setting of a MACHINE variable and remove any default value in your .conf files.

Comment: What do you mean enforce setting the MACHINE ? Even if I assign it with ":=", I still will have to do from a `local.conf.sample` file (according to convention). Which would mean that I would need a `bblayers.conf.sample` in the same directory level. Or am I missing something here?